# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 81), found shape=(None, 77)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a neural network but I am getting the following error:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 81), found shape=(None, 77)
```

I tried to find the solution to this but am unable to do so. Can someone please help me?

Here Is the code of the same

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
# Scaling the data
ss = StandardScaler()
X_train_sc = ss.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_sc = ss.transform(X_test)

# Creating our model's structure
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(81,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.18))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5) 

# Compiling the model
model.compile(loss='bce',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

# Fitting the model
history = model.fit(X_train_sc,
                    y_train, 
                    batch_size = 256,
                    validation_data =(X_test_sc, y_test),
                    epochs = 500,
                    verbose = 0,
                    callbacks=[es])
```

As suggested I have edited the code to:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import tensorflow as tf

samples = 500
X_train_sc = tf.random.normal((samples, 81))
y_train = tf.random.uniform((samples, ), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

# Creating our model's structure
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(81,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.18))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5) 

# Compiling the model
model.compile(loss='bce',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

# Fitting the model
history = model.fit(X_train_sc,
                    y_train, 
                    batch_size = 32,
                    epochs = 2,
                    verbose = 0)
```

But when I try to find the accuracy I get the same error as shown below:

```
# Scoring
train_score = model.evaluate(X_train_sc,
                       y_train,
                       verbose=1)
test_score = model.evaluate(X_test_sc,
                       y_test,
                       verbose=1)
labels = model.metrics_names

print('')
print(f'Training Accuracy: {train_score[1]}')
print(f'Testing Accuracy: {test_score[1]}')


16/16 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6613 - binary_accuracy: 0.6040
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7572/1082894889.py in <module>
      3                        y_train,
      4                        verbose=1)
----> 5 test_score = model.evaluate(X_test_sc,
      6                        y_test,
      7                        verbose=1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\sadik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1525, in test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\sadik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1514, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\sadik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1507, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.test_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\sadik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1471, in test_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\sadik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\sadik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 81), found shape=(None, 77)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input data does not have the same shape that you defined in your first layer. Make sure the features dimension of your data corresponds to the input shape in the model's first layer. Here is an example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import tensorflow as tf

samples = 500

# Create random dummy data
X_train_sc = tf.random.normal((samples, 81))
y_train = tf.random.uniform((samples, ), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

X_test_sc = tf.random.normal((samples, 81))
y_test = tf.random.uniform((samples, ), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

# Creating our model's structure
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(81,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.18))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compiling the model
model.compile(loss='bce',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

# Fitting the model
history = model.fit(X_train_sc,
                    y_train, 
                    batch_size = 32,
                    epochs = 2,
                    verbose = 0)
```

So, if your feature dimension is 77 then change `input_shape=(81,)` to `input_shape=(77,)`.

Comment: This works in training but when I try to find the accuracy of the model it again gives the same error. I have edited the question to reflect that

Comment: @Anonymous_1234 if you run `print(X_test_sc.shape)`, you will see that it still has the wrong shape and that is the problem.. Do you not understand that the example I posted is using dummy data? See my updated answer.